# Variable as jQuery selector fails without error

Tags: jquery, css

A basic form:

```
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <select name="details[1234567890123][strComplaintGroup]" id="details[1234567890123][strComplaintGroup]">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    <select name="details[1234567890123][strComplaintDetail]" id="details[1234567890123][strComplaintDetail]">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change', function(){
    var strId = $(this).attr('id');
    if( strId.indexOf('strComplaintGroup') > 0 ){
      var uniq_id = strId.substring(8,21); // details[<13 char uniq_id>][]
      var strDetail = '#details[' + uniq_id + '][strComplaintDetail]';
      console.log( strDetail );
      $(strDetail).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

I am trying to use the change the ComplaintDetail options when the ComplaintGroup is changed. My variable console.log with proper values but the ComplaintDetail Id seems to fail as a jQuery selector.

I have tried `$('#' + strDetail)` and placing the `#` in the string. No Luck.

The only thing I can guess is the `[]` are causing the failure. Valid names but not valid id/selector? As you can see I had to use `$(this)` instead of the id at the top of the JS. If so, how can I overcome this? The `[]` are required as this is a subform.

Apparently guessed correctly. Changed the `[]` to `-` for the id's and it works.
Maybe this will help someone else, I spent two days trying to figure it out.

Comment: Related [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Comment: Please submit your solution as an answer and accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You used invalid characters as `Id`.

For [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.

You can check [**What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) for more details